# how to interrupt emacs spell check (frozen)

Tags: emacs

I'm using emacs 23.1.1 (on linux) for editing of my software. I usually use the short-cut alt-shft-5 for replacing. However, if I accidently hit alt-shft-4, emacs freezes saying "Checking Spelling of CC..."

How can I interrupt/stop this to get back to my editing session?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `C-g`. It calls `keyboard-quit`.

`C-g` can unfreeze almost any hung up state. That's how people get months long
up-times for Emacs.

Comment: Emphasis on the _almost_. I'm currently trying to interrupt a hung `xref-find-definitions` and `C-g` is utterly ignored. I think it's time for `SIGKILL`... huh, it came back after a couple minutes.